# How can i send float values as post payload in aiohttp?

Tags: python, aiohttp

When i try to send a post request with one of the json in float, it shows

TypeError: Invalid variable type: mapping value should be str or int, got 77.5 ( 77.5 is the value which i want to send).

Comment: Have you tried sending `str(x)` instead of `x`?

Comment: Yes but the api end point is not accepting float in string format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert it into float. Like `x = float(x)`. It worked for me because type of x in my code was numpy.float.

Answer (score 2):

as pointed out in the first comment, send your value as string by converting it like `x = str(x)`